# How can i export as multiple words in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
import * as apple from './Apple.json';
import * as orange from "./Orange.json";
import * as pear from "./Pear.json";

export default {
  Apple,
  Orange,
  Pear
  }
```

I am using the entries inside of 'export default' to create Hyperlinks on a new page, However, i would like to export as 2 words for each line.

```
export default {
  Blue Apple,
  Red Orange,
  Black Pear
  }
```

The problem is, this breaks my application and the project won't start.
I have tried to add "" eg. "Blue Apple".
But this will not work.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this solve your issue?

```
export default {
  'Blue Apple': 'Blue Apple',
  'Red Orange': 'Red Orange',
  'Black Pear': 'Black Pear'
 }
```

Or just export an array of the string values

```
export default ['Blue Apple', 'Red Orange', 'Black Pear']
```